# Get Drill Down Values for Summary Search Using SuiteScript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, saved-searches

I'm trying to access the drill down values for a summary search using SuiteScript.

For example I have a transaction search that is set to group on the customer's name. In the UI when I click the name column hyperlink in the summary search it takes me to the filtered results of that specific customer's transactions. I would like to access these filtered values in my script.

Is there a way to do this other than create a new search for each customer in the summary search "each" loop (which has governance issues)?

My backup solution is to not use a summary search and create my own summarized objects in my script but I like to use native NetSuite functionality wherever possible.

I'm guessing it's not possible because I can find no documentation on it and the search in the UI seems to be creating a new search on the fly for the drill down. But I thought I'd ask it here to exhaust all my options and to help anyone in the future that might be looking for this answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot drill down on search results using a script.

There are a couple of ways to get where you want to be though

Simplest might be:

- Do the work in a map/reduce script.
- remove the summary fields from the search
- load the search in the `getInput()` and return the search object. Netsuite will then run the search for you.
- in the `map()` group the results by customer
- in the `reduce()` use the grouped results like they were the drill down details

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I'm essentially doing what you described but I'm using a scheduled script and looping through the search to create/group the results into an array. But the map/reduce script does sound like a cleaner option with less governance risk. Thanks again!